# how do i navigate to my listing_template?

Tags: php, bolt-cms

I have the following contenttype defined my my contenttype.yml file:

```
#Testimonials
testimonials:
name: Testimonials
singular_name: Testimonial
fields:
name:
type: text
class: large
position:
type: text
body:
type: textarea
height: 150px
listing_template: testimonials.twig
record_template: testimonial.twig
```

Now in my browser if i navigate to `http://localhost:8080/boltCMS/testimonials` I see my record_template , but if i navigate to `http://localhost:8080/boltCMS/testimonials/1` , I get an error.

Page `testimonials/1` not found.

so how do i navigate to my `listing_template` ?
is this something i can set and modify in my `contenttypes.yml` ?

If i add the following to my testimonials.twig file,

```
{{ dump(records) }}
```

I see an empty array in my browser.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that '1' is the proper slug for one of your testimonials in the database?